# How to approximate CSS box-shadow property using solid border only?

Tags: css, gaussianblur, perception

Please note that the question is not about CSS, rather about imaging, colors and a bit of mathematics. We are not talking here about how to do things in CSS. Make sure your answer does not contain a single line of CSS. Mathematics, tables, images, and formulas only, please.

I need a way (data table, formula, whatever) to calculate good enough values of `border-width` and `border-color`'s alpha channel (assuming that we use `border-style: solid`) required to mimic  `blur-radius` and `spread-radius` of box shadow of the same color (assuming there are no X and Y offsets), at least, from the point of human's eye perception.

Below is an example of black `rgb(0,0,0)` color and `blur-radius` ranging from 1px to 8px.

[image: Color = 000, Blur = 1px]
[image: Color = 000, Blur = 2px]
[image: Color = 000, Blur = 3px]
[image: Color = 000, Blur = 4px]
[image: Color = 000, Blur = 5px]
[image: Color = 000, Blur = 6px]
[image: Color = 000, Blur = 7px]
[image: Color = 000, Blur = 8px]

Currently, I'm building a data table of opacities for every next shadow pixel depending on the blur value, and if we presume that alpha blending takes place (white+black), then for the first three pixels opacities look this way (at least, in Google Chrome):

[image: Opacity of black depending on shadow blur and pixel index]

But still, even if I collect some empirical evidence and try out a few ideas, I don't know how to compare quantitatively my approximations and the original box-shadow version. If I can't measure, I can't tell whether an idea really works.

Maybe you've got some ideas how to pick best matching border width and color?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we have to answer our own questions. What did I do to answer mine - see below:

I've prepared 16x16 grid of Chrome screenshots (120px x 120px) using this utility HTML:

https://noomorph.com/approximate-box-shadow-using-border/screenshotter/

It renders a grid of `40x40` squares with shadow blur = `0..15px` and shadow size =`0..15px`.

[image: Grid of combinations]

Then I've cut the big page screenshot (1920x1920) to 256 smaller ones like this one in the link below. My snake_case convention was `<shadow-size>_<shadow-blur>.png` :

https://github.com/noomorph/approximate-box-shadow-using-border/blob/master/scripts/00_15.png

Using ImageMagick `convert`, `grep`, `sed`, `sort`, `uniq` I've produced stats for every image:

https://github.com/noomorph/approximate-box-shadow-using-border/blob/master/scripts/00_15.png.stats

Using this tiny script I produced JSON array of cases like `{ size, blur, colors: [{ count, value }]}`:

https://github.com/noomorph/approximate-box-shadow-using-border/blob/master/scripts/aggregate_stats.js

Then using simple arithmetics, basic distance formula `D=(C1-C2)^2` (where C1 and C2 are gray channels of two colors respectively) and brute force (border-width=`0..20` and RGB grayscale channel=`1..255`) I've got the mapping you can see on my demo site I've built for this:

https://noomorph.com/approximate-box-shadow-using-border/

[image: Demo screenshot]

I was trying to build some 3D and 4D plots, but still not sure about the nature of the correlation between `box-shadow` and `border`. I sincerely hope that my small research helps somebody in the future.

[image: 3D Plot]

Happy hacking!